# Monk Two Weapon Fighting + Flurry of Blows

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk, two-weapon-fighting

I am currently playing a 3.5 1/2 Medusa Monk.

At lvl 1, I took Two Weapon Fighting and my DM said that he is counting Spiked Chains as a Monk weapon.

At level 3, I took Finesse weapons as feat.

SO... adding my dex (17 mod = 3) plus my prof in monk weapons / unarmed is +1 and BaB of +2 for a total of 6 to rolls and 5 to attack. With all this combined Flurry of Blows 0/0, 2 weapon fighting would be -2/-2/-2 with the so would I have 4/4/-2 to hit rolls and 3/3/-1 to damage?

Comment: If you tell us your Str bonus I'll happily change the numbers in my answer to get the results right. I still don't get what your prof in monk weapons/unarmed should be.

Comment: Wait, can you use twf with flurry of blows?

Comment: @Levi In 3.5, you can, though at least for monks it’s not worthwhile since they have such terrible accuracy to begin with and can’t afford the feats anyway.

Comment: @Levi It's one of those issues that's like a *D&D 3.5e* WWI battle: Somebody asks *that question*, trenches are dug, thousands die on both sides, and nothing's resolved. For example, the most recent Giant in the Playground thread on the topic is from [Jan. 2017](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?510897-3-5-Monk-Unarmed-TWF), and the earliest I could find with a quick search is from [Jan. 2007](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?33336-Breaking-The-Game-With-A-Thri-Kreen-Monk).

Comment: Related: [Does Two-Weapon Fighting help Flurry of Blows?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28665/does-two-weapon-fighting-help-flurry-of-blows)

Answer (score 2):

### Attack bonus

- +2 BAB (from 3 levels of monk)
- +3 Dex
- -2 Two-weapon fighting with a light weapon in your off-hand (unarmed strike)

+3/+3

### Attack bonus with a Flurry of Blows

- +0 BAB (from 3 levels of monk, Flurry of Blows column. You don't add it, you use it instead of your usual BAB whenever you use the Flurry.)
- +3 Dex
- -2 Two-weapon fighting with a light weapon in your off-hand (unarmed strike)

+1/+1/+1

### Damage bonus

Depends on your Str bonus. Let's assume +2

- For two handed weapons it's 1.5 times your bonus, rounded down.
- For unarmed attacks it's your bonus, because monks don't halve it.

## So:

Attack 1 (spiked chain, main hand, finessable, reach)

- 1d20+1 to hit
- 2d4+3 damage

Attack 2 (unarmed, finessable)

- 1d20+1 to hit
- 1d6+2 damage

Attack 2 (unarmed, finessable)

- 1d20+1 to hit
- 1d6+2 damage

---

Horrible, I know. But that's what you get when trying to use early on features and feats that decrease your chances to hit in order to get you more attacks.

---

### A note on weapon proficiency

In 3.5e if you're proficient with a weapon you get no bonuses. If you're not proficient, you take a -4 to hit instead. Luckily, monks are proficient in every monk weapon, and your DM included the spiked chain in this number.

Comment: Minor nit-pick: "When using weapons as part of a flurry of blows, a monk applies her Strength bonus (not Str bonus × 1½ or ×½) to her damage rolls for all successful attacks, whether she wields a weapon in one or both hands." see [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/monk.htm#flurryofBlows) - so no +3 on first attack's damage... Not certain how this combines with TWF, though...